# Error at getContext () while checking permisson for LocationServices.FusedLocationApi in a fragment

Tags: android

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference

```
   if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    .....
            return;
        }
```

Comment: user getActivity().getApplicationContext()......

Answer (score 0):

Your context like

```
Context context = getActivity();//if using fragment
Context context = ActivityName.this;//if using Activity
```

and you can use below method

```
 if(context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
}
```